# I can't assign a value to my output in VHDL

Tags: vhdl, fpga, xilinx

I am stupid new with VHDL, in fact I thoroughly hate this language and am only using it because I am forced to due to a project, and am having trouble with my case when statements. Basically, I'm making a 256x8 word RAM for a project. It takes in an address, based off that address it assigns a value to the memory location, then another process where it looks for the address that was inserted, and assigns the value to my output. It is very dumb, but my teacher wants it this way. I looked at my testbench and my code and have no idea why it's messing up.

I am currently testing it out with an address of "00000001" and it should get me the same thing, but with 32 bits instead of the 8 you saw in the address, just 24 0s in front basically. [My output,](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MxYpJ.png) [The case I am trying to test,](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wj2By.jpg) [the case I am testing.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ING9p.jpg) I almost forgot, in these images, I changed it from x"00000001" to 31 0s and a 1, so these images are a little old. I shortened my code so its easier to read. In my second case it's basically the same except that I am also looking for if memRead = '1', if so then it assigns a value. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
    ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
-- Company: 
-- Engineer: 
-- 
-- Create Date:    09:45:26 03/30/2020 
-- Design Name: 
-- Module Name:    module - Behavioral 
-- Project Name: 
-- Target Devices: 
-- Tool versions: 
-- Description: 
--
-- Dependencies: 
--
-- Revision: 
-- Revision 0.01 - File Created
-- Additional Comments: 
--
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;

-- Uncomment the following library declaration if using
-- arithmetic functions with Signed or Unsigned values
use IEEE.NUMERIC_STD.ALL;

entity RAM is
Port( Address : in std_logic_vector(7 downto 0) := "00000000";
inputData : in std_logic_vector(31 downto 0) := "00000000000000000000000000000000";
Memwrite, Memread, rst, clk : in std_logic;
read_out_data : out std_logic_vector(31 downto 0));
end RAM;

architecture behave of RAM is

signal mem0, mem1, mem2, mem3, mem4, mem5, mem6, mem7, mem8, mem9, mem10, mem11, mem12, mem13, mem14, mem15, mem16, mem17, mem18, mem19, mem20, mem21, mem22, mem23, mem24, mem25,
         mem26, mem27, mem28, mem29, mem30, mem31, mem32, mem33, mem34, mem35, mem36, mem37, mem38, mem39, mem40, mem41, mem42, mem43, mem44, mem45, mem46, mem47, mem48, mem49, mem50, mem51,
         mem52, mem53, mem54, mem55, mem56, mem57, mem58, mem59, mem60, mem61, mem62, mem63, mem64, mem65, mem66, mem67, mem68, mem69, mem70, mem71, mem72, mem73, mem74, mem75, mem76, mem77,
         mem78, mem79, mem80, mem81, mem82, mem83, mem84, mem85, mem86, mem87, mem88, mem89, mem90, mem91, mem92, mem93, mem94, mem95, mem96, mem97, mem98, mem99, mem100, mem101, mem102, mem103,
         mem104, mem105, mem106, mem107, mem108, mem109, mem110, mem111, mem112, mem113, mem114, mem115, mem116, mem117, mem118, mem119, mem120, mem121, mem122, mem123, mem124, mem125, mem126, mem127, mem128, mem129,
         mem130, mem131, mem132, mem133, mem134, mem135, mem136, mem137, mem138, mem139, mem140, mem141, mem142, mem143, mem144, mem145, mem146, mem147, mem148, mem149, mem150, mem151, mem152, mem153, mem154, mem155,
         mem156, mem157, mem158, mem159, mem160, mem161, mem162, mem163, mem164, mem165, mem166, mem167, mem168, mem169, mem170, mem171, mem172, mem173, mem174, mem175, mem176, mem177, mem178, mem179, mem180, mem181,
         mem182, mem183, mem184, mem185, mem186, mem187, mem188, mem189, mem190, mem191, mem192, mem193, mem194, mem195, mem196, mem197, mem198, mem199, mem200, mem201, mem202, mem203, mem204, mem205, mem206, mem207,
         mem208, mem209, mem210, mem211, mem212, mem213, mem214, mem215, mem216, mem217, mem218, mem219, mem220, mem221, mem222, mem223, mem224, mem225, mem226, mem227, mem228, mem229, mem230, mem231, mem232, mem233,
         mem234, mem235, mem236, mem237, mem238, mem239, mem240, mem241, mem242, mem243, mem244, mem245, mem246, mem247, mem248, mem249, mem250, mem251, mem252, mem253, mem254, mem255 : std_logic_vector(31 downto 0);


signal read_data_s : std_logic_vector(31 downto 0);

begin

--Work on the RAM!

process(clk, rst, MemWrite)
begin

    if(rising_edge(clk)) then
        case Address is
        when "00000000" => mem0 <= "00000000000000000000000000000000";
        when "00000001" => mem1 <= "00000000000000000000000000000001";
        when "00000010" => mem2 <= "00000000000000000000000000000010";
        when "00000011" => mem3 <= "00000000000000000000000000000011";
        when "00000100" => mem4 <= "00000000000000000000000000000100";

        when others => read_out_data <= "00000000000000000000000000000001";
    end case;
    end if;
end process;

    process(clk)
    begin
        if(Memread = '1') then
            if(rising_edge(clk)) then
        case Address is
        when "00000000" => read_out_data <= mem0;
        when "00000001" => read_out_data <= mem1;
        when "00000010" => read_out_data <= mem2;
        when "00000011" => read_out_data <= mem3;
        when "00000100" => read_out_data <= mem4;

        when others => read_out_data <= "00000000000000000000000000000000";
    end case;
    end if;
        end if;
        end process;
end behave;
```

Comment: You don't provide a [mcve]. There are defects in your design. You have multiple drivers (assignments in multiple processes) for read_out_data. It's not 256x8 nor does it perform random access writes. You write multiple locations in a single clock (continuously). Your RAM should use a signal of an array type with address converted to an integer type instead a collection of cell signals. Your synthesis tool documentation will have example implementations, you don't need to reinvent an RTL RAM here.

Comment: If you were using Vivado in User Guide 901 (Synthesis) there's sections on RAM HDL Coding Guidelines and Initializing RAM contents. For ISE (14.7) there's an applicable xst.pdf Ch. 3. XST HDL Coding Techniques, RAMs and ROMs HDL Coding Techniques, RAMs and ROMs Coding Examples and Initializing RAM Coding Examples (e.g. UG627).

Comment: ummm ... are you not allowed to use an array?

Comment: My teacher kinda sux at teaching this stuff and this language isn't really my strong suit, because I'm used to high level languages and don't know mess with this in my day to day. But the issue is solved, because the TA got back to me. Tank you to everyone who commented.

Answer (score 0):

My teacher kinda sux at teaching this stuff and this language isn't really my strong suit, because I'm used to high level languages and don't know mess with this in my day to day. But the issue is solved, because the TA got back to me. Tank you to everyone who commented.

Basically, I needed to create a separate signal for my others condition to handle the output, instead of just setting the output in my others condition.